# Can't create cs nor config files using SvcUtil.exe

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I'm getting tired so kick me if I'm missing something very obvious. When I execute the following in PowerShell:

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcUtil.exe http:
>   //.../Test01.svc?wsdl /out:fil1e.cs /config:file2.config'

I'm expecting *file1.cs* and *file2.config* to appear in the current directory as well as some informative text to be printed in the prompt window. However, I get neither.

I've checked that the *SvcUtil.exe* is at that location (running just it gives me those larget-that-characters). I've checked that the service is up and running (the link is copied from the info displayed when accessing it).

I can create a service reference in VS12 and then it works as supposed to but I'm very curious as to why I can't get it to be executed from the command line of Power Shell.

What do I miss?!

Comment: Three questions: 1) What's the current directory when you run this?  2) Have you tried running svcutil.exe manually from a cmd processor rather than from PowerShell?  3) Can you open and inspect "`http://../Test01.svc?wsdl`" in a browser?

Comment: @STLDeveloper (1) *...\\bin\\myWebApp.dll*, (2) with head lowered in shame - no... and after some tweaking it gave me what I wanted, problem solved, (3) not that it matters now but yes, I can. Thanks! Put it as a reply so I can green-check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have a bug there...  I'm not sure that you can have spaces in the filename of the executable or command arguments unless you wrap them in quotes.

Instead of:
    `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcUtil.exe http:
 //.../Test01.svc?wsdl /out:fil1e.cs /config:file2.config'`

perhaps use:
    `'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcUtil.exe" http:
 //.../Test01.svc?wsdl /out:file1.cs /config:file2.config'`

note:  `/out:fil1e.cs ==>  /out:file1.cs`

Comment: Yupp, that's the issue (plus I can't do that from PS for some reason - I need to go by *cmd*). Problem solved.

Comment: Good luck, Konrad.  I've built a few web services interfaces in this "wsdl-first" way - and I don't care for it.  Inevitably I wind up having to interface to something that won't even pass simpel WS-I conformance tests.

Comment: Perhaps my methodology is becoming obsolete. I've always started by exposing a set of methods through an endpoint and **then** letting "the other team" consume them. My rationale is that we always know what data we want to "display" but not always how it's supposed to be used. What approach would you recommend? I'm all ears.

Comment: I think that's a great approach when you can use it.  In my case I have to work with a lot of other teams who've built web services using lots of different tools and build clients, in .NET that consume their services.  For one reason or another their services don't pass muster, yet still I am compelled to consume them as-is.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work unless you also give your output a full path, like so:

```
/out:C:\fil1e.cs
```